# dont understood lambda expression on scheme

Tags: scheme

i try to realize what this expiration, and don't get it.

```
( lambda (a b) (lambda (x y) (if b (+ x y a) (-x y a)))
```

i think,
a is a number, and b is #t or #f,
on the if statement we ask if b is true, if yes return first expression(sum 3 numbers), else the second(Subtract 3 numbers)

what i need to write on Racket to run this?
i try

```
(define question( lambda (a b) (lambda (x y) (if b (+ x y a) (-x y a)))))
```

and than

```
(question 5 #f)
```

and nothing not going well in this language.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer as I don't want to do your homework for you.

First of all formatting and indenting your code is going to help you in any programming language.  You almost certainly have access to an editor which will do this.  Below I've done this.

So, OK, what does a form like `(λ (...) ...)` denote?  Well, its a function which takes some arguments (the first ellipsis) and returns the value of the last form in its body (the second ellipsis), or the only form in its body in a purely functional language.

So, what does:

```
(λ (a b)
  (λ (x y)
    ...))
```

Denote?  It's a function of two arguments, and it returns something: what is the thing it returns?  Well, it's a form which looks like `(λ (...) ...)`: you know what those forms mean already.

And finally we can fill out the last ellipsis (after correcting an error: `(-x ...)` is not the same as `(- x ...)`):

```
(λ (a b)
  (λ (x y)
    (if b
        (+ x y a)
        (- x y a))))
```

So now, how would you call this, and how would you make it do something interesting (like actually adding or subtracting some things)?

Answer (score 0):

```
(lambda (a b) (lambda (x y) (if b (+ x y a) (- x y a))))
```

is a function that takes two arguments (that's what `(lambda (a b) ...)` says).

You can use the substitution method to discover what it produces.
Apply it to `5` and `#f`:

```
((lambda (a b) (lambda (x y) (if b (+ x y a) (- x y a)))) 5 #f)
```

[Replace `a` with `5` and `b` with `#f` in the body]:

```
(lambda (x y) (if #f (+ x y 5) (- x y 5)))
```

And this is a function that takes two numbers and produces a new number.
(Note that the `#f` and the `5` became fixed by the application of the outer lambda.)

It's easier to use the function if we name it (interactions from DrRacket):

```
> (define question (lambda (a b) (lambda (x y) (if b (+ x y a) (- x y a)))))
> (question 5 #f)
#<procedure>
```

which is as expected, based on the reasoning above.

Let's name this function as well:

```
> (define answer (question 5 #f))
```

and use it:

```
> (answer 3 4)
-6
```

or we could use it unnamed:

```
> ((question 5 #f) 3 4)
-6
```

or you could do it all inline, but that's a horrible unreadable mess:

```
> (((lambda (a b) (lambda (x y) (if b (+ x y a) (- x y a)))) 5 #f) 3 4)
-6
```